# API PUT request fails to update things

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, api

I am following this tutorial.

https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/webapi/consume-web-api-put-method-in-aspnet-mvc

This is what I have:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        Employees employee = null;

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:44339/api/employees");
            //HTTP GET
            var responseTask = client.GetAsync("employees/" + id.ToString());
            responseTask.Wait();



            var result = responseTask.Result;
            if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var readTask = result.Content.ReadAsAsync<Employees>();
                readTask.Wait();

                employee = readTask.Result;
            }
        }

        return View(employee);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Employees employee)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:44339/api/employees");

            //HTTP POST
            var putTask = client.PutAsJsonAsync<Employees>("employees", employee);
            putTask.Wait();

            var result = putTask.Result;
            if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {

                return RedirectToAction("ApiTest");
            }
        }
        return View(employee);
    }
```

It just returns me back to ApiTest with no update happening. I have been trying to figure this out but it is killing me.

Comment: You need to learn about the task based asynchronous pattern. Don't use .Wait() and .Result when working with asynchronous tasks. Mark your method as async, and `await` your asynchrounous calls. If your method returned an object, make its return type a Task<T> where T is the type of object it was previously returning. If it was previously void, make its return type a `Task`. I don't know that it will fix your issue - but it's the proper way to write asynchronous code. The tutorial you're using is showing you how to do things incorrect - I'd run away as fast as possible.

Comment: @mason3 so is that a bad tutorial to follow?

Comment: Yep. I wouldn't trust a tutorial that's showing me bad code practices like that.

Comment: @mason can you point me where I could do what that tutorial is showing but in a better way?

Comment: I would recommend reading [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) by Stephen Cleary. Apart from that - look for videos from official sources such as Microsoft. There's plenty on YouTube. Async isn't too hard if you follow some simple rules. But if you stray outside that, you can quickly screw things up and make hard to debug code.